# useEffect to manipulate secondary value

Tags: reactjs

Hi im making an interactive price calculator for a sales site that allows the user to click on features that increase a numeric value.  I have decided to do the entire thing in useState useEffect before i bring in context to the website.

What you are seeing is the useeffect part i dont want to bring in context yet but im setting up to do that later.

```
const ToolSelect = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        setInitialState(initialState);
    }, []);

    const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState({
        service: "",
        services: [],
        plan: "",
        type: "",
        clicked: false,
        price: 0
    });

    const { number, service } = initialState;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (type === "cash") {
            setPrice(number * 1.1);
        } else if (type === "accrual") {
            setPrice(number * 1.2);
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setClicked(true);
        if (plan === "starter") {
            setPrice(1000);
        } else if (plan === "essential") {
            setPrice(2000);
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (service === "tp") {
            services.push(service);
            setPrice(number + 800);
        } else if (service === "pr") {
            services.push(service);
            setPrice(number + 1000);
        } else if (service === "entity") {
            services.push(service);
            setPrice(number + 300);
        } else if (service === "compliance") {
            services.push(service);
            setPrice(number + 2000);
        }
    });

    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    const [type, setType] = useState("");
    const [plan, setPlan] = useState("");
    const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(true);

    const onChange = e => {
        setPrice({ ...price, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        setType({ ...type, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        setPlan({ ...plan, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        setServices({ ...service, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };
```

Comment: you have not added any dependencies to `useEffect` and hence this will keep executing the `useEffect` fn for every `set` state. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: adding either setValue or value to the useEffects gets me an initialization error

Comment: code updated please help me

Comment: you want to replace `3useEffects` with single `useEffect`?

Comment: i want to sum up a price as i interact with selecting values on the form